# Chrome extension not turning off

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently creating a chrome extension that redirect users and add paramaters if someone enter a specific url in chrome.

Everything is working as expected, except that the extension is still doing the redirect once its off (when toggling off through the icon).

What is wrong with my code ?

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Country Switcher",
  "description": "Redirect Google to a different host",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "off.png",
      "default_title": "icon"
    },
  "background": {"scripts":["background.js"]},
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "*://*/*",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
var host_fr = "https://www.google.fr";
var param_fr = "";
var toggle = false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png"});
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function redirect(details) {
         return {redirectUrl: host_fr + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1] + param_fr};
    },
    {
        urls: [
            "*://www.google.com/*",
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
    );  
}
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png"});
  }
});
```

THank you very much

PS : I am a beginner...

Answer (score 3):

You are *adding* a listener, and doing nothing to *remove* it.

Two possible paths here:

1. Remove the listener in `onClicked` handler when `toggle === false`:

   ```
   function handler(details) { // Must be non-anonymous
     return {redirectUrl: host_fr + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1] + param_fr};
   }

   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
     toggle = !toggle;
     if(toggle){
       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png"});
       chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
         handler, /* your other parameters */
       );
     }
     else{
       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png"});
       chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(handler);
     }
   });
   ```

   I am not 100% sure how `removeListener` works with `webRequest`, considering the complex `addListener`, but that's the theory
2. Modify the listener (and only add it **once!**) to take `toggle` into account:

   ```
   function handler(details) {
     if (toggle) {
       return {redirectUrl: host_fr + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1] + param_fr};
     } else {
       return {}; // do nothing
     }
   }

   // Do this at the top level
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
     handler, /* your other parameters */
   );     

   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
     toggle = !toggle;
     if (toggle) {
       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png"});
     } else {
       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png"});
     }
   });
   ```

   This method is **much easier**.

Comment: Hey Xan, thank you for this :-)

I've tried the second method (I've removed the "other parameters" part) but nothing is firing. The icon is not changing state and the redirection is not working at all.

Comment: [Debug](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging), then. If nothing is firing - there's a syntax error somewhere. You're supposed to add back the parameters I cut out for brevity.

Comment: I see you're new to SO; to close this question, accept this answer.